# What`s wrong with my EmailSender class in C#?

Tags: c#, email

I have tried to write a working email sender class in C# but when I try to test (send email) it waits for like a minute and then says that there is no connection and nothing has been sent. The problem may be in the code, however there is a chance I have not done SMTP server thing properly. So is my code correct?

```
class EmailSender
    {
        static public string SendEmail(string subj, string text, string emailTo)
        {
            try
            {
                MailAddress to = new MailAddress(emailTo, "m");
                MailAddress from = new MailAddress("email address from which I send email");

                MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
                message.Subject = subj;
                message.Body = text;
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient("some smtp server", 587);
                mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                mySmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                mySmtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email address from which I send email", password: "bxzvxfobjudqdmyh");

                mySmtpClient.Send(message);
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "Error occured. " + ex.ToString();
            }
        }

    }
```

I have watched barely all videos about sending emails in C#, but it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work". You have to be more specific! Do you get an exception? Or do you just receive no e-mail without any visible error message? Or something completely different?

Comment: Check whether the server accepts connections. (Is there a firewall?) Check if you can connect to it with `telnet` or `curl`. Try to get logging information (in particular the SMTP dialog) from the C# library you use. Do you need to log in / authenticate before sending?

Comment: try using a test SMTP server like https://mailsnag.com. That should rule out connectivity/firewall issues since it is not on a standard SMTP port.